# NextJS Heroku deploy not updating environment variables

Tags: heroku, next.js

I have a NextJS app setup and deploying to Heroku. When I update my Heroku environment variables, the new variables are not actually being used on the live site. I've tried updating the variables in the Heroku console, via the CLI, editing the variables, removing the variables and then adding them back, and have restarted the dynos multiple times. I thought that maybe this was a caching issue and I just needed to wait a bit for the changes to propagate, but it's been 12 hours now and the new variables are still not being used on the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try printing your env variables using `heroku-cli`? Likewise.. `heroku config:get VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: @Ronnie Yeah, the CLI is returning the correct variables. The dashboard is showing the correct variables too.

Comment: If you've really changed the environment variables on Heroku (through CLI or through the dashboard) and you've restarted the dyno then the only other thing is that the "environment variables" inside your app aren't environment variables but are hardcoded. This can for instance happen when you build your project for a static app. Then it'll use whatever environment variable that was set during build. You'll need to show code or maybe you can resolve it on your own. Changing environment variables does not retrigger a build.

Comment: I just figured this out. @TinNguyen you are correct. I had to trigger a re-build since I've not configured the app to use environment variables at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to trigger a rebuild to get the environment variables to update. In order to update environment variables without building (at runtime), you need to make some changes to the webpack.

Comment: I am also running into this issue, which changes did you have to make?

Comment: @PeteDermott I didn't have to make any changes, I just had to trigger a rebuild. Heroku doesn't actually re-build the app when you update the environment variables. Since Next tries to do SSG, the only way to get the updated environment variables is to re-build.

Comment: This worked for me. You have to do a manual deploy in order for the env/config vars to update. From the Heroku Dashboard for the app in the Deploy tab > Manual deploy > click "Deploy Branch".

Comment: If you dig into your app's Next.js compiled JavaScript, you will see that your `process.env` variables *get baked into the JavaScript bundle at build time*; they do not reference `process.env` at runtime. Heroku does not re-run `npm run build` when the settings change, so your Next.js app never re-bakes the `process.env` into the compiled JavaScript. Manually deploying, however, will run `npm run build` on your app, which is why this answer works.